# Howto solve my Realtek RTL8821CE issue running Ubuntu 20.04 on an All in One HP 24-f0083ns and 24-f0084ns?

Tags: 20.04

The Realtek RTL8821CE adaptor is recognised and the Additional Driver from Software&Update installs properly but it does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the BIOS Menu and access to the Setup. Go to Secure Boot and turn it Off. That does the trick.

So far everything is working fine (Display, Keyboard, Mouse, Sound, Microphone, Camera, Bluethooth, USB 2.0 and 3.0 Ports, Gigabit Ethernet Port, WIFI 2,4GHz and 5GHz, Suspend/Power Off...).

PS: I had to change my Router Channel Number WIFI from "Auto" to "36, 40, 44, 48" to get the 5Ghz WIFI recognised.

Comment: No need to to turn Off your Secure Boot, just set up your MOK password as explained when you install the Drivers. It works fine too!